# ng-repeat with radio button toggle on a specific condition

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a couple radio button toggles generated by ng-repeat. By default, I would like the first radio buttons all toggled, and if a conditional applies, I would like only that radio button toggled.

```
<li ng-repeat="method in itemGroup.ShippingMethods">
    <input ng-model="itemGroup.SelectedShippingMethod" 
           ng-change="changeShipping(itemGroupKey, 
           itemGroup.SelectedShippingMethod)" 
           type="radio" 
           name="Shipping" 
           id="method.Name" 
           value="method.Name" 
    />
```

In my JS file:

```
$scope.itemGroup = { SelectedShippingMethod: "Express" };
```

The intention of the code is to have the first button toggled by default, unless the condition is hit (Express Shipping), in which that button would be toggled.

In a list of [Standard, Fast, Speedy], Standard radio button would be toggled. In a list of [Standard, Fast, Express], Express radio button would be toggled.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you want to create a radio button group you need to apply the [same name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio).

Comment: @JeroenHeier All the names are the same

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this on you radio inputs:

```
ng-checked="$first || item == 'Express'"
```

Note: `item == 'Express'` will be different according to the structure of your data and looping.

Here's a simple demo of this solution:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.itemslists = {
    list1: ['Standard', 'Fast', 'Speedy'],
    list2: ['Standard', 'Express', 'Speedy'],
    list3: ['Standard', 'Fast', 'Express']
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <ul style="list-style-type: none" ng-repeat="(list, items) in itemslists">
    <h3 style="margin-bottom: 2px">{{list}}</h3>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="{{list}}" ng-checked="$first || item == 'Express'"/>
        {{item}}
      </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: This solution would not work if Express is not the last item. Since this is an ng-repeat, ng-checked would execute only the last item in the list and in the case of ['Standard', 'Express', 'Fast'], Standard would be checked because of $first.

Comment: @AndrewHsu not really, checkboxes are checked if it's the first one in the list or it equals to 'Express' no matter where that might be. I added another list (list2) to demonstrate the case you mentioned.